# What does the "PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR" error mean in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I was playing around with some SSL settings in Emby, and I managed to get this 'Secure Connection Failed' error which says:

> An error occurred during a connection to emby.home.local:8920. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

[image: Secure Connection Failed Error Message]

What is this error message trying to tell me? Is there any Firefox documentation where this error message is listed?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Comment: @GrahamPerrin I don't remember what I did to create the issue, but I still want to know more information about this error (preferably firefox documentation).

Comment: To me, it happened when trying to access a Docker image with an ASP.NET Core app and I have not [enabled the use of development certificates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: I had the same question about a different Firefox error. If you ever find where these errors are documented, please let me know! :-)

Answer (score 25):

This error means that Firefox wasn't able to establish a secure connection
and that all cipher suites failed (Firefox reached the end of the list).

Here are some thoughts about the cause:

- The post says that you "was playing around with some SSL settings",
  so it is possible that you have specified some cipher variants that are not
  supported by Firefox or by the website you are trying to reach.
  Try to reset your settings to their initial state.
- This can happen if you use a proxy or VPN or have other software that
  intercepts the connection and acts like a man-in-the-middle.
  Check your settings, and if using a proxy or VPN, try instead to connect directly.
- It can also be the antivirus software. Try to disable or uninstall it.
- Profile corruption is also a possibility.
  Go into `about:profiles` and use "Create a New Prof‌ile" and set it to default.
  If this is working, export your bookmarks from the old profile and import them
  to the new one and continue using it instead.

Comment: For me it is the opposite. Direct connection sometimes fails, and it shows this message. A connection through my VPN works. My ISP is Claro Colombia.

Comment: @Nicolay77: Better ask this in a new post with all the pertinent information.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem using AWS LightSail. It ended up that port 443 was blocked by the server and I had to open the port up through the console.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when I had a typo in the country name (UA instead of US) on an IIS Server, and FireFox returned the indicated error (egg on face).

Answer (score 1):

I have a paid VPN service and I use several add-ons. All are designed to prevent tracing back to my actual IP Address, remove tracking cookies, prevent auto-install trojans or viruses and prevent any other known hacking methods. I find that when the site I want to visit cannot trace back to see my actual IP address, it gives an error code "Proxy end of file error" because it was bounced to more than one IP address. I will then disconnect the VPN, keep all the other add-ons active, and make sure to connect directly to the site I want. When I'm done, I logout, close the browser, turn the VPN on again and re-launch my browser.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that simply switching to another VPN server or opening the URL in chrome (webkit)  can fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is often not related to the browser. In our case it was also not a configuration thing of nginx, but a wrong setting of the firewall. So logically, when I say that often has nothing to do with the browser, server-side and not client-side. Accordingly, it was not a proxy or VPN.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue when using **Surfshark VPN** while working with virtual machines in **VMware Fusion**.

I could not access the **AWS console** or login into **GitHub**

Tried a lot of things to fix it such as:

- Reinstalling my VMWare
- Setting a new VMWare virtual machine

but none worked.

**Here's what worked**

I noticed that this error started after I updated the **Surfshark VPN**

Changing the connection protocols resolved the issue.

- Open the Surfshark application
- Click on **Settings**
- Then **Advanced**
- And lastly, **Protocol**. Here, you will find all of the available protocols, including **IKEv2**, **OpenVPN UDP/TCP**, **WireGuard**, and even **Shadowsocks**.

[image]

So for me, I changed it from **WireGuard** to **IKEv2**, and that solved it.

**Resource**: [Why am I unable to access some websites while connected to Surfshark?](https://support.surfshark.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021935660-Why-am-I-unable-to-access-some-websites-while-connected-to-Surfshark-)

**That's all**

Comment: I also faced the same with Surfshark but their IKEv2 slow af. I ended up switching to native WireGuard client after getting the config file. That fixed it.