# What does Firefox's PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR mean?

Tags: firefox, tcp

When I browse to https://unesco.org from Firefox, I get the error PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR. But https://www.unesco.org works.

I couldn't find Firefox's documentation on this error despite several Google and DuckDuckGo searches.  A [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1492755/what-does-the-pr-end-of-file-error-error-mean-in-firefox) also failed to point to any Firefox documentation of these errors. While https://unesco.org stopped exhibiting this error before I finished answering my own question, real information on what PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR means is still rare, so I'm posting it anyway.

What does PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR mean?

Answer (score 2):

It simply means the TCP connection to the site was forcibly closed, either by the site itself, or by some proxy (such as a firewall) between your Firefox browser and the site.

An attempt to connect to the site from Python:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('unesco.org',443))
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()
s2 = context.wrap_socket(s,server_hostname='unesco.org')
```

yields:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

This same error is produced when a server does you the courtesy of letting you know that a port is not open on that server.  In this case, it is possible my institution was blocking my connection to unesco.org for some reason.  Or that there was a temporary issue with the site, which has now resolved.

I happened to come across the same error for a different url (https://decodeinfo.com) the next day.  Here are the errors by the different browsers:

### Firefox

> #### Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to decodeinfo.com. (OK, so maybe this is a different error?)
> PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
>
> Error code: PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
>
> ```
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
> ```

### Chrome

> #### This site can’t be reached
>
> decodeinfo.com
> unexpectedly closed the connection.
>
> Try:
>
> - Checking the connection
> - Checking the proxy and the firewall
> - Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

### Edge

> #### Hmmm… can't reach this page
>
> It looks like decodeinfo.com closed the
> connection
>
> Try:
>
> - Checking the connection
> - Checking the proxy and the firewall
> - Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

That Chrome and Edge are now based on the same engine is reflected in their very similar responses.

But most importantly, these browsers also give clearer error messages. They clearly explain what happened (the TCP connection was closed) and provide good debugging tips.