# Cant connect to some websites

Tags: firefox, internet, fedora, web

## Info

Recently, some websites that I connect to just doesnt work

Currently, the websites that dont work are:

- youtube.com
- twitter.com

When connecting to them, I get 1 of 3 errors:

- PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
- The connection has timed out
- PR_IO_TIMEOUT_ERROR

This is not a  dupe of [What does the "PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR" error mean in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/1492755/what-does-the-pr-end-of-file-error-error-mean-in-firefox) as in their question, they were playing around with ssl certificates.

A while before this happened, I was trying to make "custom local domains" that would only work for my network (ex. example.local) but it didnt work so I removed it, thats all I remember of that

```
$ dig youtube.com
;; communications error to 192.168.1.1#53: timed out
;; communications error to 192.168.1.1#53: timed out

; <<>> DiG 9.18.14 <<>> youtube.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 37968
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1220
; COOKIE: a0a1c12b15c7df9a78eac8c7645b648551d539e76783b483 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;youtube.com.           IN  A

;; Query time: 204 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed May 10 14:31:49 PKT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 68
```

```
$ nslookup youtube.com
;; communications error to 192.168.1.1#53: timed out
;; communications error to 192.168.1.1#53: timed out
;; communications error to 192.168.1.1#53: timed out
;; no servers could be reached
```

dnscheck.tools results

```
Your DNS resolvers are:
Cloudflare

    103.22.200.61 ns: darl.ns.cloudflare.com Singapore, Singapore, SG103.22.200.62 ns: darl.ns.cloudflare.com Singapore, Singapore, SG172.69.245.17 ns: cruz.ns.cloudflare.com Karachi, Sindh, PK172.70.146.171 ns: cruz.ns.cloudflare.com Singapore, Singapore, SG172.70.146.172 ns: cruz.ns.cloudflare.com Singapore, Singapore, SG2400:cb00:179:1024::ac45:f511 ns: chloe.ns.cloudflare.com Karachi, Sindh, PK2400:cb00:412:1024::ac46:92ab ns: chloe.ns.cloudflare.com Singapore, Singapore, SG2400:cb00:412:1024::ac46:92ac ns: chloe.ns.cloudflare.com Singapore, Singapore, SG2400:cb00:632:1024::6716:c83d ns: chloe.ns.cloudflare.com Singapore, Singapore, SG2400:cb00:632:1024::6716:c83e ns: chloe.ns.cloudflare.com Singapore, Singapore, SG

Google LLC

    172.253.12.129 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.12.132 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.12.133 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.12.193 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.12.194 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.12.195 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.12.196 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.12.197 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.13.129 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.13.130 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.13.131 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.13.132 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.13.133 ns: ns1.google.com Milan, Lombardy, IT172.253.217.133 ns: ns1.google.com Turin, Piedmont, IT

IE-GOOGLE-2a00-1450-4000-1

    2a00:1450:4025:1803::101 ns: ns1.google.com San Francisco, California, US2a00:1450:4025:1803::104 ns: ns1.google.com San Francisco, California, US2a00:1450:4025:1803::105 ns: ns1.google.com San Francisco, California, US2a00:1450:4025:1805::102 ns: ns1.google.com San Francisco, California, US2a00:1450:4025:1805::104 ns: ns1.google.com San Francisco, California, US2a00:1450:4025:1805::105 ns: ns1.google.com San Francisco, California, US

Great! Your DNS responses are authenticated with DNSSEC:

    correct P-256 signature... pass
    invalid P-256 signature... pass
    expired P-256 signature... pass
    correct P-384 signature... pass
    invalid P-384 signature... pass
    expired P-384 signature... pass
    correct Ed25519 signature... pass
    invalid Ed25519 signature... pass
    expired Ed25519 signature... pass
    unsigned domain... pass
```

DNS leak test results

| IP | HOSTNAME | ISP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 172.70.146.223 | NONE | Cloudflare |
| 172.70.92.38 | NONE | Cloudflare |

### *IMPORTANT*

Youtube.com doesnt work on firefox or chrome on other devices connected to the same network but the youtube mobile app still works to an extent, it takes a while to load sometimes at at other times it doesnt load at all and I have to try again

## What I've tried

I tried disabling firefoxes dns over https (It was already disabled so that didnt help)

I tried making another profile

Setting static dns to use 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1, This did not fix the problem but it did bring up some new responses to dig & nslookup

```
$ dig youtube.com
; <<>> DiG 9.18.14 <<>> youtube.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4439
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;youtube.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
youtube.com.        237 IN  A   172.217.21.46

;; Query time: 142 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed May 10 23:20:36 PKT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

```
$ nslookup youtube.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   youtube.com
Address: 172.217.21.46
Name:   youtube.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4019:806::200e
```

it seems like its responding properly but firefox still doesnt load the pages

Comment: Do you have the same issues in all browsers? (If I may ask, maybe there is some censorship/blocking going on in your ISP/Country?)

Comment: I've seen this kind of issue seldomly while on my work laptop. It seems TCP connections on my company VPN randomly die. Haven't been able to reproduce it consistently do debug it though. Do any of the suggestions here help? https://superuser.com/questions/1492755/what-does-the-pr-end-of-file-error-error-mean-in-firefox

Comment: @YisroelTech I tried this out with the only other browser I had (Itch.io desktop app built-in browser) and youtube still doesnt work

Comment: Try to temporarily disable your security software and antivirus. Try also to change your DNS server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "PR\_END\_OF\_FILE\_ERROR" error mean in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/1492755/what-does-the-pr-end-of-file-error-error-mean-in-firefox). It could also be a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1620627/why-does-medium-com-resolve-to-localhost-ip-address-of-127-0-0-1) question instead.

Comment: @Ramhound I've already tried answers from [Why does “medium.com” resolve to localhost IP address of 127.0.0.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/1620627/why-does-medium-com-resolve-to-localhost-ip-address-of-127-0-0-1) but Im gonna add nslookup and dig outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of people reporting that enabling [**DNS over HTTPS**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https) caused them this issue.

Try disabling ***DNS over HTTPS*** and see if it helps:

1. Click the menu button and select **Settings**.
2. In the ***General*** panel, go down to ***Network Settings*** and click the **Settings** button
3. In the dialog box that opens, scroll down to ***Enable DNS over HTTPS***
4. **Deselect** the ***Enable DNS over HTTPS checkbox***
5. Click **OK** to save your changes and close the box

Test again loading those websites.

---

Given that the `nslookup` and `dig` commands show an error communicating/getting a response from the router's DNS, you should try setting your DNS servers statically (you can use Google's `8.8.8.8` and Cloudflare's `1.1.1.1`) on the PC and then test again.

1. Open **Settings**
2. Go to **Network**
3. Click on the **gearwheel** next to the network device you want to modify (Wired or wireless)
4. Select **IPv4**
5. Toggle the ***Automatic*** DNS **OFF**
6. Input your desired DNS (you can try `8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1`)
7. Click **Apply**

Comment: This option was already disabled, so sadly, this doesnt help

Comment: Added something to try in light of the dig results

Comment: I just tried it but it still didnt fix it, but it did bring new outputs to dig and nslookup, which I added to the question @YisroelTech

Comment: In Firefox, can you try a DNS test like https://dnscheck.tools/ or https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ to see who it shows are your DNS resolvers? Another thing to try, can you actually Enable the DNS over HTTPS (which was disabled in your Firefox)? Try those two things separately.

Comment: results added to the question

Comment: What about enabling DNS over HTTPS?

Comment: Nope, but I just found out that this is a problem between my entire network

youtube.com doesnt work but the app does..

Comment: In that case, I'd go back to my initial comment on your question... there is some censorship/blocking going on there.

Comment: I have done a little bit of research and found out that youtube, twitter, facebook, and a bunch of different social medias got banned.
I will just mark this answer as correct

Comment: If I may ask... By whom? (There are obviously ways to circumvent such blocks... but that's not for here.)

Comment: Quote from an article: "Access to YouTube has been blocked by the Pakistani government, along with other social media platforms like Facebook and Twitter. This is in response to widespread criticism over the arrest of Imran Khan" theres alot going on